# Understanding result of fetching CKRecords with new async/await API

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ios15

I am a bit confused on how to deal with complex Swift data types, their assignment to variables and accessing the values within. Hopefully someone can clarify the following:

when trying to get data from SwiftUI and CloudKit, and while trying to rewrite a CK function to conform to async/await, I have the following line of code:

`let result  = try await container.privateCloudDatabase.records(matching: query)`

now this line is ***supposed*** to get all of the records matching the specified query from the cloud private database and return some CKRecords

The old function did this as follows:

```
container.privateCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (rec, err) in 
    for record in rec {
        print("Found this record: \(record)")
    }
}
```

and this worked great because `perform(_:inZoneWith:)` would return a CKRecord and an Error, those were "picked apart" in the `(rec, err) in` statement and passed into the loop to be iterated.

With the new async/await method, I am trying to simply await and assign a variable to all of the records that are found and then iterate the data returned, pick out the CKRecords and perform whatever task I want.

What I am confused with is, when I attempt to pick out the data from the returned result, in several ways, I just get errors. I am not fully understanding how to describe the data structure of the returned values and I think this is the root cause of the issue.

I have tried a few things and have gotten the following error messages:

if I try:

```
let (result, err)  = try await container.privateCloudDatabase.records(matching: query)
```

When I use (trying to append the CKRecords to an array of CKRecords I created earlier):

```
for record in result {
   self.myCKRecordArray.append(record)
}
```

the error message states specifically:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Dictionary<CKRecord.ID, Result<CKRecord, Error>>.Element' (aka '(key: CKRecord.ID, value: Result<CKRecord, Error>)') to expected argument type 'CKRecord'`

Which definitely gives me some clues. I believe that my `result` variable contains a Dictionary<CKRecord.ID, Result<CKRecord, Error>>.Element, or a list of key/value pairs wherein the CKRecord.ID is the key for the Result<CKRecord, Error> value.

This is pretty confusing.. So If I understand that correctly, then:

```
        for thisDict in result {
            let (realResult, err) = result[thisDict.key]
            print("Found this record: \(realResult)")
        }
```

should theoretically result in the output of each CKRecord assigned to realResult, right? I just get the error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

I tried to change it to `valueForKey` and also give it more context, but no change from the error message:

```
let (realResult, err) = result(valueForKey:thisDict.key) as Result<CKRecord, Error>
```

I just believe that I do not fully understand ***how*** to properly access the CKRecord from something that is represented by a: `Dictionary<CKRecord.ID, Result<CKRecord, Error>>.Element` data structure.

Any insight into understanding is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

***Update***

Ok, based on the answer from @Shadowrun, if I understand correctly:

The result from:

```
let result  = try await container.privateCloudDatabase.records(matching: query)
```

is a tuple type. Which means that it has two elements, the first being the Dictionary of data and the second being the queryCursor.

If I want to iterate over the Dictionary portion of the tuple and get the CKRecord out:

```
        for rec in result.0 {
            self.myCKRecordArray.append(try rec.value.get())
        }
```

This does not give me any errors.. Am I understanding this correctly?

***2nd update***
it does work as expected this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s an equivalence between functions that return a `Result<T, E>` and functions that either return `T` or throw an `E`. And similar equivalence for functions returning tuple of `(T?, E?)`

When mapping functions with completion handlers to async functions, they become throwing functions, so should just be:

```
let result = try await container….
```

The error, if any, is thrown

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thank you, but when trying to iterate that result, it is a much more complex data type than just an array of CKRecords: For-in loop requires '(matchResults: [CKRecord.ID : Result<CKRecord, Error>], queryCursor: CKQueryOperation.Cursor?)' to conform to 'Sequence'

Comment: So result is a tuple type, first element is dictionary, you can iterate over that? Can’t for in a tuple.

Comment: I have updated my question at the bottom to see if I understand what you are saying properly.. My errors have gone away,  I do not have an actual device updated to iOS 15 for testing at the moment to verify operation. I think I got it tho..

Comment: i was able to test and it does work as expected. Thank you for the info

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of being pedantic, may I suggest reading the docs?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckdatabase/3856524-records

```
func records(matching query: CKQuery, 
    inZoneWith zoneID: CKRecordZone.ID? = nil, 
    desiredKeys: [CKRecord.FieldKey]? = nil, 
    resultsLimit: Int = CKQueryOperation.maximumResults) async throws -> 
        (matchResults: [CKRecord.ID : Result<CKRecord, Error>],     
          queryCursor: CKQueryOperation.Cursor?)
```

So your result is tuple. Call your result `tuple`. Then `tuple.matchResults` is a dictionary keyed by ID whose values are Result objects.

The best way to extract value from a Result object, in my opinion, is to use `get`. This has the advantage that it either returns a value or throws, and you can cope nicely with that.